# SQL Server 2008 R2: Select with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table test:

Table: `Test`

```
create table test
(
number int,
name varchar(10)
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into test values(111,'PersonA');
insert into test values(211,'PersonB');
insert into test values(311,'PersonC');
insert into test values(111,'PersonA');
insert into test values(212,'PersonB');
insert into test values(313,'PersonC');
insert into test values(111,'PersonA');
insert into test values(211,'PersonB');
```

Now I want to display those records, like if a person used two different numbers
then it has to show there details.

If I want to see 1 to 2 then it has to show me the details of person who have used 
1 to 2 numbers:

Result : for 1 to 2

```
number  name
------------
111     PersonA
211     PersonB
212     PersonB
311     PersonC  
313     PersonC
```

If I want to see 2 to 2 then it has to show me the details of person who have used 
2 to 2 numbers:

Result : for 2 to 2

```
number  name
---------------
211     PersonB
212     PersonB
311     PersonC  
313     PersonC
```

Comment: What you mean by 1 to 2 and 2 to 2. question is not clear. As per my understanding you are basically looking for distinct numbers

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer, 1 to 2 means the numbers used by person.

Comment: 1 or 2 unique numerals in 'number' column. Is that you mean by it?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer, Count of number column.

Comment: sorry buddy. it is still not clear. what is 2 to 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have done it using CTE.

For 1 to 2:

```
with cte
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Number) as a,Name from test
    group by name
)   
select DISTINCT x.Number,z.Name 
from cte z
inner join test x
ON z.name = x.name
WHERE z.a between 1 and 2;
```

Result:

```
number  name
-------------
111     PersonA
211     PersonB
212     PersonB
311     PersonC
313     PersonC
```

For 1 to 2:

```
with cte
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Number) as a,Name from test
    group by name
)   
select DISTINCT x.Number,z.Name 
from cte z
inner join test x
ON z.name = x.name
WHERE z.a between 2 and 2;
```

Result:

```
number  name
-------------
211     PersonB
212     PersonB
311     PersonC
313     PersonC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

Comment: This wont work. All the columns have to be either in group by or have an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, are you looking for this :-

```
---- for 1 or 2
Select  Distinct
        *
From    test
Where  Cast(number As Varchar(20)) Like '%1%' Or Cast(number As Varchar(20)) Like '%2%'

---- for 2
Select  Distinct
        *
From    test
Where  Cast(number As Varchar(20)) Like '%2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from test
Where number in (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM test)
```

Comment: Assuming there are no NULLs, this will just return all the rows